# PostgreSQL could not connect to server on AWS

Tags: postgresql, aws

I am currently using AWS's free tier. I am receiving the error message:

`could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "xxxxxxxxx" (-) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

This has happened twice now with 2 different databases. Each time after creating the DB on AWS, they both worked perfectly fine for 4 or 5 days without any connection issues. I have not changed any settings in pgAdmin, psql, or AWS since creating the two databases, so I am unsure of the cause.

EDIT:
I just logged into pgAdmin, and now I can connect. I guess my updated question is 'has anyone had this problem with AWS'? I did absolutely nothing aside from checking the firewall as dezso suggested, and this was 4 hours after I restarted the database and still couldn't connect. Also, just to clarify, the database was definitely available after restarting it when I tried to, but couldn't connect the last time.

EDIT:

It has once again temporarily stopped connecting and no settings have changed.

Comment: Is the DB running?  The fix IP public/accessible and from where you try?  Any firewalls set up along the route?

Comment: It is running, It is publicly accessible and using rds-launch-wizard-1 without any settings having been changed since it was previously connecting in psql and pgAdmin. I executed 'netstat -a -n' and did not see port 5432 listed. I have tried rebooting the db on aws, but that did not help either.

Comment: I know it sounds dumb, but are you sure you are connecting to the DB you think you are connecting to?  The `netstat` output suggests that at least the port is not open.  This might be due to the DB not running, among others.

Comment: Yes I am positive as I purposely put the latest one I am working on as the only one that automatically remembers my password in pgAdmin because I previously thought that I may have been entering it incorrectly. It started connecting again around 4pm yesterday after not connecting for about 4 hours, and it was available in AWS during that 4 hour span. I can currently connect. I just haven't seen this exact issue with AWS posted as I am nervous about future problems.

Comment: Was there ever a solution for this?

Comment: I have not been able to replicate this and have since moved off free tier.

Comment: Just to check that 'must I download the postgreSQL software in my computer in order to run them via python